# fill AspxPopupControl with aspxGridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

Im using aspxPopupControl with AspxGridView in it. Is it possible to set control to fill all popup cause now when I try to resize that popup there is a lot of free space at the top and bottom when I increase width od the popup. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at the new [ASPxGridLookup](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/aspnet/archive/2010/08/27/new-asp-net-gridlookup-control-coming-in-v2010-vol-2.aspx) control? I would assume that it is just what you need.

Also, see the [online documentation of the `ASPxGridLookup` control](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebASPxGridLookupASPxGridLookuptopic).

Answer (score 0):

Gruber,

Try the approach mentioned in this issue [Q253230](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q253230.aspx):

```
<dx:ASPxHtmlEditor ID="ASPxHtmlEditor1" runat="server" Height="100%" Width="100%" ClientInstanceName="HtmlEditorBody" ResizingMode="Postponed"></dx:ASPxHtmlEditor>

<dx:ASPxPopupControl ...>
    <ClientSideEvents 
        AfterResizing="function(s, e) {
            HtmlEditorBody.SetHeight(s.GetHeight() - 25); HtmlEditorBody.SetWidth(s.GetWidth() - 25);
        }"
        BeforeResizing="function(s, e) {
            HtmlEditorBody.SetHeight(MIN_SIZE);
            HtmlEditorBody.SetWidth(MIN_SIZE); 
        }"
/>
```

While that code is for the ASPxHtmlEditor, you can adapt it for the ASPxGridView.